# Is this black mold/wall damage fixable without professional help?

Tags: walls, mold

Renting an apartment, had a bad flood last year, restoration company came and left (and forgot about) an industrial fan for 6 weeks, afterwards they said everything should be fine. Bookcase was not moved. After moving the bookcase (roommate moving out), we found this seemingly significant damage. Is this fixable/cleanable without professional help?

Dimension from wall on left is 65", "blocky" section is 48"x18"[image]

Comment: I would recommend removal but hydrogen peroxide 3% minimum may kill it help there I use concentrated hydrogen Peroxide to kill mold and fungus all the time. Black mold the only way to tell if it’s the bad stuff is to test it. Thousands of mold types and a few hundred are toxic to us. Even if I was removing that I would spray it if a dirty water flood up to 7% , clear water like broken water line 3-5%. It may be possible to save if the hydrogen peroxide clears it up and it is only surface/ Sheetrock is solid but that is hard to tell from a photo , probably why we suggest replacement.

Answer (score 1):

That section of the wall must be cut out.   The drywall and plaster and then behind it must be cleaned.  You would cut out about 12" over the molded area.   I see mold too next to it.

Fans help having a huge mold issue.   If you have a flood and standing water fans are not the fix though.   They just keep the issue from getting out of control.

Answer (score 1):

That whole section of drywall should be cut out and the inside of the wall inspected for more damage/mold. If it's an exterior wall or if there's insulation in there, it should be removed too. Then you need to clean the area with a mold killer. I have used vinegar because it kills surface mold and gets in to kill the roots. Once all that's done, then replace the insulation and do the drywall repair. If this is your unit, this is a good DIY project and there's a lot of information on this site to help you out. If you're renting, check with your landlord about getting the repairs done.